# Adding event listeners in Google Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying to write a Google Chrome extension, and so far my code looks like this:

```
callback_function = function () {
    chrome.tabs.create({selected: true, url: "http://www.google.com"});
};

document.addEventListener(chrome.history.onVisited, callback_function());
```

If I'm reading the documentation correctly, `chrome.history.onVisited` is an event that fires whenever someone visits a website, and `chrome.tabs.create` creates a new tab with the specified URL.  And if I understand correctly, an "event listener" waits for events to be fired, and runs the callback function whenever the event is fired.

So by my logic, this code should create a new Google tab every time I visit a website.  But for some reason, it only creates the Google tab when I first reload the extension.  Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ouch. No, that's not how Chrome API events work. They are not DOM events.

Read the documentation here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events

In short, you need to take the event object (`chrome.history.onVisited`) and call its method, `addListener`:

```
chrome.history.onVisited.addListener(callback_function);
```

Also, note: you want to pass a reference to the function itself (`callback_function`), and not the result of its execution (`callback_function()`)

Comment: Thanks, it works now!  I just have one more question: if they are two different types of events, how come the Google tab loaded when I reloaded the extension?  Shouldn't it never reload?

Comment: That's because your code tries to pass the results of `callback_function` (to the wrong code) - see my last remark. So the function is executed.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes so much sense now!  Thanks!